# type dependant edge creation in polymorphic graph structure with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, graph, sqlalchemy

My problem is as follows. I've got a directed graph structure in sqlalchemy with polymorphic vertices and I'd like to restrict the edge creation type dependant. The following code defines the graph structure.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Edge(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'edge'

    head_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('vertex.id'), primary_key=True)
    tail_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('vertex.id'), primary_key=True)

class Vertex(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'vertex'

    id = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )
    predecessors = relationship('Vertex', 
                        secondary='edge',
                        primaryjoin="Vertex.id==Edge.head_id",
                        secondaryjoin="Vertex.id==Edge.tail_id",
                        backref='successors')
    type    = Column( String(50) )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'Vertex',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }
```

The construction of graphs is quite simple

```
#creates two vertices with a directed edge from v1 to v2
v1 = Vertex()
v2 = Vertex()
v1.successors.append(v2) # v1->v2
```

The problem is 'How can i restrict the edge creation type dependant.
E.g. Edges from class A to class B are allowed but not vice versa.

```
class A(Vertex):
    pass

class B(Vertex):
    pass

v1 = A()
v2 = B()
v1.successors.append(v2) #allowed
v2.successors.append(v1) #forbidden
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class Vertex(Base):
    # ...

    @validates('successors')
    def validate_successors(self, key, value):
        check_value = True
        # @todo: insert the validation logic here
        if type(self) == B and type(value) == A:
            check_value = False
        assert check_value, 'Invalid Edge: not allowed to link from [{fr}] to [{to}]'.format(fr=type(self).__name__, to=type(value).__name__)
        return value
```

**edit-1:** Added code sample where the validation is delegated to the derived classes:

```
class Vertex(Base):
    # ...

    def _validate_successors_impl(self, value):
        return True

    @validates('successors')
    def validate_successors(self, key, value):
        self._validate_successors_impl(value)
        return value

class A(Vertex):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'A'}

    def _validate_successors_impl(self, value):
        if type(value) == B:
            assert check_value, 'Invalid Edge: not allowed to link from [{fr}] to [{to}]'.format(fr=type(self).__name__, to=type(value).__name__)

class B(Vertex):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'B'}
```

Comment: How would you move the validation logic to the derived classes, e.g. A has to know it doesnt accept a B but not Vertex.

Comment: Create a `validator` in the base, and delegate the validation to the derived using polymorphism. I will update the answer with the sample code shortly...